# macOS Catalina static linking library issue

Tags: c++, macos, clang, static-libraries, static-linking

I have c++ project where I have 3 libraries. Two static and one dynamic which is dependent from first two. Those two are building successfully and third is crashing while building because lack of symbols from static libs. There is also warning which I think is crucial here:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/pwpw/Desktop/plid/Core/../Common/libcommon64.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64

I am using QT to build the project. The problem occurs only on MacOS and my version is now 10.15.2

Comment: are you using homebrew? a quick google brings up a few homebrew users with the same issue, reinstalling homebrew seems to fix it

Comment: which Qt version do you use and what kind of build tools (CMake/qmake) ?

Comment: Qt in version 5.12.5 with clang64 and I am building with qmake. I think Homebrew is not directly included in building process.

Comment: Still I didn't found solution. I removed /usr/local/bin from my PATH and still not working. Updating also didn't help. I am linking two libraries, which have size 8MB.